# End plotted line when condition is met (crossover)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can draw a line from the high of a specific time range(2000-0000) up to 0400.

The line is drawn from the end of the 0000 to 0400.

My problem :

If the price cross the line (high) based on a crossover condition, I want the line to be drawn up to the bar the condition is met. Else the line should be extended to 0400.

How can I do that?

```
// My code

highRange = SessionHigh(range, "GMT-5")

line = bool(time(timeframe.period, "0000-0400"))

crossHigh = ta.crossover(high, highRange)

plotLine = plot(highRange, color=line ? color.new(#f1074d, 50) : na, linewidth=2, title="Line")
```

Comment: still need this?

Comment: @samsupertaco Yes, would appreciate some help here, thank you